# Use gcc without setting environment variables?

Tags: gcc, environment-variables

I need an information. Is it possible to use gcc without set environment variables? It is quite complicated to explain why, but basically i have to come up with a method to do that. I have everything installed, i just want to use gcc through the binaries.

Is there a way to do that?

The reason is that i have two different version of gcc, which is the one i usually use for compilation etc. On the other side i have to develop a couple of scripts that compile C sources using the other version and I don't want to mess up with the environment variables.

Comment: Not sure why you are worrying about environment variables. if you want to use a different version, use its full path such as: `/usr/local/bin/gcc`  (or whatever the path) directly?

Comment: There's the LD_LIBRARY_PATH that concerns me a bit, if the versions are different should be different the variable itself? or at least the content of the path pointed by that variable should be different. No?

Comment: Why are you using LD_LIBRARY_PATH at all?

Comment: Of course it's possible to use GCC without setting environment variables, that is the normal way to do it!  If your question is really about running the programs (not using GCC) then you might find https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/libstdc++/manual/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths and the documentation it links to useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify your gcc compiler in command

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.4 CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.4 make
```

if you use cmake, use next cmake parameters

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-4.4 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++-4.4 .
```

LD_LIBRARY_PATH shows to application where app can find linked shared objects, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not needed for making

Comment: Your first command is related to the use of the makefile, is it? So there's no relationship between the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and the compilation it self?

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is needed when the program is run. It is not needed during compilation or linking (GCC know how to find its own libraries, of course).

Comment: Ok that's important to know... so when i compile just using the binary directly the result of the compilation is independent from the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, no?

Comment: yes, first command will use makefile for make

if you want to compile using gcc directly then use full path to needed gcc binary

Comment: Yes, result of compilation is independent from the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Assuming we are two different users on the same machine, if my environment (LD_LIBRARY_PATH) is different from his own one then the execution result could be potentially different, is it?

Comment: Yes and no
Linker linking your program with shared objects and from functions must be called. if function placed in glibc.so.6 then with glibc.so.5 application will not work, but if you are has different glibc.so.6 you can get different results.
About ld_library_path. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is path to shared objects which system not contains.

Comment: The LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable contains a colon-separated list of directories that are searched by the dynamic linker when looking for a shared library to load.

The directories are searched in the order they are mentioned in.

    If not specified, the linker uses the default, which is /lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib.

for example:
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. is useless`
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib is useless`
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/MXB/lib has sense`